# How to stop cat shelf split

Tags: strength

I have two cat shelfs (brought, sorry).  The problem that i have is that they are sometimes quite weak.

How do I make them more secure?  What do I need to do?

**This is the bottom of the shelf**
[image: Bottom of the cat shelf]

**This the actual split from the top of the shelf**

[image: Shelf Split area]

Comment: I think we need to see more pics (of the underside in particular) to give guidance. A split like this strongly suggests to me that they're put together badly, without regard for wood movement. If that is the case only a fairly major revision would solve the problem and prevent its recurrence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a cantilever design

[image]

It looks like someone (or somecat) has put more weight on it than it is capable of supporting (was it located somewhere a child might have been tempted to try it?)

After repairing the split (disassemble, glue and screws or clamp, reassemble) I would add some bracing struts to the underside, secured to the wall.

Comment: Its purely the cats and they are only small as well.  The actual joint failed on both of them...I have since brought two more and have placed wood screws through the entire back of the shelf.  fingers crossed that work.s

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me as though the joint where the side pieces meet the back has failed. I'm not sure how it is currently joined, but I think this would be the best strategy:

1. Force some wood glue into the crack
2. Drill a hole through the back and into the side piece
3. Glue a dowel into the hole
4. Clamp the joint back together and let it sit until the glue is dried

If the dowel method is beyond your skills/tools, then just glue the crack and then use an appropriately sized wood screw.